# Why are cursor keys in Excel moving the viewport rather than the active cell?

Tags: ms-office

Excel for Mac (2011) should move the currently active cell when I use the cursor keys. Currently, it is moving the viewport in the document. Is there a way to switch this back to the default setting? I cannot find anything in Excel's preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like Scroll Lock is somehow activated on your copy of Excel. IF you have a large keyboard with an <kbd>F14</kbd> key, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F14</kbd> can turn on and off Scroll Lock. If you don't have such a keyboard, or access to such a keyboard, it gets more complicated.

Microsoft support posted [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118467) about the various methods of deactivating Scroll Lock. They either involve connecting a keyboard with a <kbd>F14</kbd> key or removing your Excel preferences file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an F14 key, you can use the on-screen keyboard. In Windows click the Windows key and type "osk" and then press enter. Works like a charm.

Comment: My original question was about Excel for Mac. Funnily enough, OS X doesn't have a Windows key.