# No Scroll Lock on Apple Keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, kvm

My StarTech sv215micusba KVM requires that I use <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but my Apple keyboard doesn't have a Scroll Lock key.  I found this reference:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1216

But it refers to key combinations used for Windows functionality (driver-dependent).  What combo would I need to press in order to send the correct sequence to my KVM switch?

Comment: Would it be worth naming the exact KVM in case anyone has any specific experience, e.g. modifying the key combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having had a look at the [StarTech SV215MICUSBA manual (PDF)](http://www.startech.com/media/products/SV215MICUSBA/Manuals/SV215MICUSBA.pdf), on page 7 it says:

> To initialize Mac keyboard mapping, please execute the following
>   hotkey  sequence:
>
> [scroll],[scroll], [F2], [Enter]
>   or
>   [ctrl] [ctrl] [F2] [Enter]
>
> Once this has been done, the following keyboard mapping will apply:

Then in the table below, it indicates that the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> Lock key on a PC keyboard is mapped to <kbd>F14</kbd> on a Mac keyboard.

Assuming you have a full Apple keyboard, its probably worth trying this out.

Answer (score 0):

Some KVM switches have [alternate methods](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Keyboards-and-Keyboard-Mice/EX110-keyboard-and-Scroll-Lock/td-p/9599/page/8) of switching besides <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>. I would read the manual to see if there is any similar feature on your KVM.

Otherwise, you might need to resort to [having an additional PC keyboard](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-26398.html) hooked up to the KVM switch with the sole purpose of sending the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large Apple keyboard with an <kbd>F14</kbd> Key, Shift-<kbd>F14</kbd> has been [documented](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34858/9388) to work as a Scroll Lock key in Excel. I don't have any documentation about your sv215micusba device, but if you have a large Apple keyboard, that key combination might work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the free remap tool for macbook available at https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en, enable functions keys in the settings of the keyboard, and remap the key you want to F14.

Example for F6 to F14: add the following xml in your private.xml file inside ~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Swap F6 to PrintScroll</name>
    <identifier>private.swap_F6_to_printscroll</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ 
    KeyCode::F6,
    KeyCode::F14
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions were working for me, and I was unable to remap my KVM's (Syba SY-KVM31034) hotkey, so I wrote this simple tool that sends the necessary double scroll lock signal to my KVM. It can even be assigned to a key combo: https://github.com/benjaminstout/osx-kvm